# How do I delete Questions that I posted?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

The site has " Can I delete an answer I posted?" but I don't want to delete answers I want to delete questions. I don't really want to delete it on this SE, but I might want to on the automotive SE, because my question was apparently bad? I want to know this for future use.

Comment: I *highly* recommend you read/reference the [Help Center](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) and [Privilege Page](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) in the future.  They address many questions about site functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions):

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> - has zero answers
> - only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes
>
> Simply click the delete link underneath the question.